# Why does numpy.angle(0+0j) answer pi instead of zero

Tags: python, numpy

I am creating an array of complex numbers and compute the angle.

When I set the magnitude to zero, I expect the angle to always be zero. However, I get pi if the phase is in the range of pi/2 to pi.

Here is my example code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def main():
    # s = np.full(360, 1)    # Use this instead of np.zeros to get expected results
    s = np.zeros(360)
    f = 1 / s.size
    t = np.arange(s.size)
    s = s * np.exp(1j * 2*np.pi * f * t)

    fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 2)

    axs[0,0].set_title("Magnitude")
    axs[0,0].grid()
    axs[0,0].plot(t, abs(s))

    axs[1,0].set_title("Phase")
    axs[1,0].grid()
    axs[1,0].plot(t, np.angle(s))
    # axs[1,0].plot(t, np.arctan2(np.imag(s), np.real(s)))

    axs[0,1].set_title("Real")
    axs[0,1].grid()
    axs[0,1].plot(t, np.real(s))

    axs[1,1].set_title("Imag")
    axs[1,1].grid()
    axs[1,1].plot(t, np.imag(s))

    plt.show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

[Here is the output of the test program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IiskD.png)

I have also tried arctan2 and get the same behaviour.

Comment: Not all of these zeroes are "positive", which is a bit of a strange thing to say, but floats have a negative zero after all. The docs say nothing about negative zeroes, that might imply that they were supposed to be treated as positive zeroes, but it might also imply nothing.

Answer (score 1):

> Why does numpy.angle(0+0j) answer pi instead of zero

I did check [`numpy.angle` docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.angle.html#numpy.angle), they claim

> Although the angle of the complex number 0 is undefined,
> numpy.angle(0) returns the value 0.

so I did checked that

```
import numpy as np
assert np.angle(0+0j) == 0
```

and it does work as described in docs, I have used NumPy version 1.18.1, please check your version of NumPy. Maybe you are using one such ancient that described extension to `numpy.angle` was not implemented?

Comment: Check `np.angle(-0.0-0.0j)` as well just to be sure, otherwise you're really checking a different case

Answer (score 0):

As @harold points out, not all elements are the same:

```
In [154]:     s = np.zeros(360)
     ...:     f = 1 / s.size
     ...:     t = np.arange(s.size)
     ...:     s = s * np.exp(1j * 2*np.pi * f * t)
     ...: 
In [155]: s
Out[155]: 
array([ 0.+0.j,  0.+0.j,  0.+0.j,  0.+0.j,  0.+0.j,  0.+0.j,  0.+0.j,
        0.+0.j,  0.+0.j,  0.+0.j,  0.+0.j,  0.+0.j,  0.+0.j,  0.+0.j,
       ...
       -0.+0.j, -0.+0.j, -0.+0.j, -0.+0.j, -0.+0.j, -0.+0.j, -0.+0.j,
       -0.+0.j, -0.+0.j, -0.+0.j, -0.+0.j, -0.+0.j, -0.+0.j, -0.+0.j,
        ...])
In [156]: np.angle(s)
Out[156]: 
array([ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
        0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
        0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
        ...
        0.        ,  3.14159265,  3.14159265,  3.14159265,  3.14159265,
        3.14159265,  3.14159265,  3.14159265,  3.14159265,  3.14159265,
        3.14159265,  3.14159265,  3.14159265,  3.14159265,  3.14159265,
        ...])
```

You had a question about the results of `np.angle`, so the logical debugging step is to examine the argument to that function.  Next step is to figure out why some elements are `-0.0+0.0j`.

Answer (score 0):

Answering to my own question:

The root cause seems to be the behaviour of math.atan2, as in the following code:

```
print(math.atan2(0.0, 0.0))
print(math.atan2(0.0, -0.0))
print(math.atan2(-0.0, 0.0))
print(math.atan2(-0.0, -0.0))
```

which prints on my system:

```
0.0
3.141592653589793
-0.0
-3.141592653589793
```

It is the same results as if the real part was non-zero, so that seems to be the rationale:

```
print(math.atan2(0.0, 1))
print(math.atan2(0.0, -1))
print(math.atan2(-0.0, 1))
print(math.atan2(-0.0, -1))
```

So coming back to numpy, the documentation of numpy.angle says that:

> Although the angle of the complex number 0 is undefined, numpy.angle(0) returns the value 0.

This seems to be incorrect if the real part of the complex number is -0.0.